# In a dataframe I had a column like this. 9(05) X(5) X(15) X(15) X(15) S9(07) S9(2)V9(2) I want to split them into four different into columns

Tags: python, pandas

INPUT
      9(05)
      X(5)
     X(15)
     X(15)
     X(15)
    S9(07)
S9(2)V9(2)
OUTPUT
a   b   c   d
9   05  NaN NaN
X   5   NaN NaN
X   15  NaN NaN
S9  07  NaN NaN
S9  02  V9  2

Comment: What's `X` in your output? Is it also a string? Are you basically trying to count the number of chars in the strings and replace with another string like `X(<number>)`?

Comment: X represents type of element like alphanumeric or numeric.X(<number>) represents the size occupied by that type of element.

Comment: So `output` is still a string? For example with this input: `'YYYY'` you'll get `output = 'Y(4)'`?

Comment: yes, I need it like that.

Answer (score 0):

Something like that should do it:

```
input='XX','XXX','XXXX'

output = []
for elem in input:
    output.append(elem[0]+'(' + "%02d"%len(elem) + ')')
print output
```

Output is:

```
['X(02)', 'X(03)', 'X(04)']
```

Please keep in mind this will assume that all the elements in your string are equal to each other, if that's not the case then the first char in the string will be used in the output.

NOTE: if you're on python3 then the last line should read:

```
print(output)
```